# jQuery datatable setting column design and value in success callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, datatables

I have written a following code for my datatables which fills up the table with contents from my DB like this:

```
 if (datatable != null)
            datatable.destroy();

        datatable = $('#tableProducts').DataTable({
            "pageLength": 50,
            "bLengthChange": false,
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "filter": true,
            "orderMulti": false,
            "bSort": false,
            "ajax": {
                "url": "/Bulk/LoadData/",
                "type": "POST",
                "data": {
                    "username": $(".sellerInput").val(),
                    "drange": $(".select2").val()
                },
                success: function (data) {
                }
            },
            "columns": [
                      {
                          "targets": -1,
                          "data": "ImageURL",
                          "name": "Title",
                          "render": function (data, type, row) {
                              return '<td><img src=' + data + '></td>';
                          },
                          "autoWidth": true
                      },
                {
                    "data": "Sales",
                    "name": "QuantitySold",
                    "render": function (data, type, row) {

                        return '<td>' + data + '</td>'
                    },
                },
                 {
                     "data": "CurrentPrice",
                     "name": "CurrenctPrice",
                     "render": function (data, type, row) {

                         return '<td> <b>$ ' + data + '</b></td>'
                     },
                 }
            ]
        });
```

And this works just fine if I don't specify the success callback. If I specify the success callback like this ( also shown in code above):

```
"ajax": {
       "url": "/Bulk/LoadData/",
       "type": "POST",
       "data": {
                "username": $(".sellerInput").val(),
                "drange": $(".select2").val()
               },
                success: function (data) {
               // some custom code here and + filling up datatable with data from my DB...
               }
   },
```

The problem here is if I specify the success callback and then update other parts of my HTML page, then the datatable doesn't loads up the data in DB..

My question is, how can I manually specify the data source for datatable  if I override the datatable's success callback function in order to update more parts of my HTML page insteade of just the datatable itself?

Can someone help me out ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `dataSrc` instead of `success` to get the response data

**Try this:**

```
"ajax": {
       "url": "/Bulk/LoadData/",
       "type": "POST",
       "data": function (d){
                d.username: $(".sellerInput").val(),
                d.drange: $(".select2").val()
       },
       "dataSrc": function (data) {
               // some custom code here and + filling up datatable with data from my DB...
            console.log(data);
            return data;
       }
   },
```

**Note:** Also you are trying to send extra param's as `username` and `drange`, so in DataTable we should use `"data":function(d){` as function to send extra param

[**Official Documentation**](https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/custom_vars.html)

Comment: Why return data? I would like to update the HTML with this data.. can't I do something like this then (for example): $("#Title").text(data.Title); or something similar?

Comment: check [here](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax#highlighter_306232) to manipulate data and return is required to process data in dataTable

Comment: Oh okay I understand you now. But some of the returned data is used to manipulate the other parts of my page, not just datatable :D

Comment: @User987 Exactly :) Also check the how to send extra data param using data as function

Comment: Ty so much Singh my friend ! I learnt something useful today ! =D Okay .. So I've tested it out this way but it says it expects ; ?

Answer (score 1):

From the [**docs**](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax#Description) :

> success - *Must not be overridden as it is used internally in
>   DataTables*. To manipulate / transform the data returned by the server
>   use ajax.dataSrc.

So simply use

```
ajax: {
   url: "/Bulk/LoadData/",
   type: "POST",
   data: {
     "username": $(".sellerInput").val(),
     "drange": $(".select2").val()
   },
   dataSrc: function (data) {
     // some custom code here and + filling up datatable with data from my DB...
     return data
   }
},
```

instead.