# jQuery Prepend to DataTables Pagination

Tags: jquery, pagination, datatables, prepend

I have a jQuery DataTables (latest download) where I am trying to display a loading animation beside the pagination controls on the bottom. It should be easy and part of the following code works:

```
$("#table_main_paginate").css("width", "50%");
$("#table_main_paginate").prepend($("<div> jjjj </div>"));
```

above code is after the DataTable has already initialized and the `CSS` for `width` indeed does work. But the second line of code does not work. My javascript file is loaded after other javascript files are loaded and the above code is inside the `documentReady` function.

So what's happening?

Thanks!

Comment: Share your HTML

Comment: Thanks. But it's very large. Basically,  var mainTable = $('#table_main').DataTable( { ....   } ); then above code.

Comment: try `setTimeout(function(){ //your code },2000)` and see if it works

Comment: Yes, it does! However the Div shows up on top/misaligned. Thanks!

Comment: @Meengla however sometimes jquery plugins takes some time to initialize completely, you can also change `setTimeout` time to `500` so that it works even faster

Comment: I will accept your Answer if you post it sir? Thanks!

Comment: Only problem I see now is that after first pagination, the animation does show. Not after the subsequent one. I will need to figure that out in my code. Thanks.

Comment: @Meengla sorry i just checked your comment, added solution in the answer, let me know if you need any other help! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
setTimeout(function(){ 
   $("#table_main_paginate").css("width", "50%");
   $("#table_main_paginate").prepend($("<div> jjjj </div>"));
},2000);
```

However, sometimes jquery plugins takes some time to initialize completely

Comment: Yes, this does work but with a value of 2000 for timeout; in case of 500 it didn't seem to. Also, the prepend doesn't work after the first pagination event--presumably, because this is server side, the table gets redrawn. I will try to fix it but may move on to just showing the div below pagination. Thanks @Mahesh!

Comment: @Meengla you welcome!!  If it is server side, then you can use `"dataSrc": function(){}` callback function for your dataTable ajax to add this code on every page after ajax request complete

Comment: you can check my recent answer to see how `dataSrc` works [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44332041/jquery-datatable-setting-column-design-and-value-in-success-callback/44332310#44332310)